# Very slow delete/update in MariaDb ColumnStore Server using primary key

Tags: sql, database, mariadb

We have table with InnoDB engine (on MariaDB columnstore server) that have 5 million rows and primary key of 2 columns.  DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `interest` (
  `src_id` TINYINT NOT NULL,
  `id` binary(36) NOT NULL,
  `account_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `instrument_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL,
  `time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `interest` decimal(16,2) NOT NULL,
  `auto_incr` bigint(20) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`src_id`, `id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and both of these queries takes 4-5 seconds to execute

```
DELETE FROM interest WHERE `id`='52f35ddb-94d0-4744-bb3c-f3ae8100dc8e' AND `src_id`='1';

UPDATE interest SET interest = 1 WHERE `id`='52f35ddb-94d0-4744-bb3c-f3ae8100dc8e' AND `src_id`='1';
```

The result of the EXPLAIN is:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED DELETE FROM interest WHERE `id`='52f35ddb-94d0-4744-bb3c-f3ae8100dc8e' AND `src_id`='1';
```

[image]

It looks like that primary key doesn't take effect because it scans more than 50% of the rows.

I exported the data from this table (in MariaDB columnstore server) and import it in table within normal MariaDB server and there is no such problem. Both query execute under 10ms.

We are using latest version of MariaDB columnstore: 1.2.5

Comment: I'm lost -- First you talk about InnoDB, then you say you are using ColumnStore.  Which is it?

Comment: Are there 5M rows in the InnoDB Fact table and 3.6M rows in the ColumnStore Summary table?  Or...???

Comment: MariaDB have 2 severs (https://mariadb.com/downloads/): MariaDB server, MariaDB columnstore server.  MariaDB columnstore server supports both InnoDB and Columnstore table engines ( here is the confusion because the table engine have the same name as the db server). I have 5M rows in InnoDB fact table on MariaDB columnstore server ( as you can see my DDL I'm defining explicitly the table ENGINE ). And both DELETE and UPDATE queries for this InnoDB table are slow

Comment: I updated my question and tried to make it more clear. Try to read it again and if it is still confusing tell me to try update it again :)

Comment: OK, "columnstore" is a 'red herring'.  And I got confused.  Your Question is entirely about slow queries against InnoDB.  (So far, I am puzzled.)

Comment: This _may_ help:  `ANALYZE TABLE interest;`

Answer (score 0):

Columnstore uses slightly customized version of MDB and there is place where custom code alters optimizer settings but this only works for queries that have CS tables. JFYI Enterprise 10.4 and community 10.5 will have Columnstore as a normal engine with the non-custom MDB version.